# Printing a poster from pdf results in wrong colors

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, pdf, print-production

I have A0 poster with 2 science images that were taken by a spacecraft. On top of it I have graphs and some text. When I print it as A4 pdf on my office small printer - the colors are fine. When I print it as A0 on my university poster printer the colors are bad in multiple ways - over saturated, faded and etc. However, the text and graphs that I added on top of the images are totally fine! I work in Adobe Illustrator CMYK format of course! Help!

P.s. I have had a few step (compression, cropping) in Adobe Photoshop if that matters at all. Poster printer is HP DesignJet Z2100 Photo Printer.

Comment: Maybe your university printer uses rgb instead of cmyk? Just try to print in rgb.

Answer (score 0):

The printing options of a desktop printer and a photo printer can vary a lot. There are several factors that influence a good printing:

- Monitor Calibration
- Document color profile
- Paper type

Assuming all this is correct on your computer and document, reading on the HP DesignJet Z2100 Photo Printer site, there's a step by step to follow before printing a color photo that you should follow:

https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c00744560#AbT10

Comment: The other is, of course, that most 'consumer' [& even some commercial these days] printers don't want CMYK at all, they want RGB, usually just sRGB.

Answer (score -3):

I suggest you should print directly from the Adobe Illustrator or better still convert it to a JPEG. The option of a Desktop printer and Photo printer is very different.

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GDSE! Sorry, but I'm downvoting because I think converting the design to a JPEG is a bad advice. It will rasterize all vector object and probably make the printed result less sharp and crisp than it could be.